# How to set the value of gcTrimCommitOnLowMemory to enabled in a shared service running .NET 6?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

we have a service written in .NET 6 and deployed to Google Cloud where it is running on Linux.
The project doesn't have the Aspnet.config file in the .NET directory, so I can't follow this MS [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/optimization-for-shared-web-hosting) to enable gcTrimCommitOnLowMemory.

For this projects the settings are defined in appsettings.json or in launchsettings.json or in .csproj file or in the Startup.cs.

What is the correct syntax to set gcTrimCommitOnLowMemory enabled="true" in one of these files?

Comment: At least some of the GC behavior (e.g., `gcServer`) can be controlled by environment variables. [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/garbage-collector) provides details, but it's not clear to me if what you want to change is covered by anything there. It's worth trying to set `DOTNET_gcTrimCommitOnLowMemory`, even if it's not mentioned.

Comment: [This project's wiki](https://github.com/JustArchiNET/ArchiSteamFarm/wiki/Low-memory-setup#gctrimcommitonlowmemory) seems to suggest that it would work, as it's mentioned by name there.